# Why Instagram public API has not been working with authentification

Tags: web-scraping, instagram

Two days ago, I was able to use Instagram's public API  https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1 to scrape profiles, but today when I login and try to get the JSON file for a specific account I get this error message:

> for (;;);{"__ar":1,"error":1357004,"errorSummary":"D\u00e9sol\u00e9, une erreur s\u2019est produite.","errorDescription":"Essayez de fermer, puis d\u2019ouvrir \u00e0 nouveau la fen\u00eatre de votre navigateur.","payload":null,"hsrp":{"hblp":{"consistency":{"rev":1005611792}}},"lid":"7104438514481245052"}

Comment: There are other API but it for search, maybe you can use it https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?query=username

Answer (score 2):

If you open this link from the browser, you will get this error

[image: IG error 1357004]

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"error":1357004,"errorSummary":"Sorry, something went wrong","errorDescription":"Please try closing and re-opening your browser window.","payload":null,"hsrp":{"hblp":{"consistency":{"rev":1005641975}}},"lid":"7106533583738392223"}
```

I have found that if we removed the cookie named **ds_user_id**, data will get returned just fine

I removed it from my browser and things loaded just fine

[image: IG error 1357004 solution]

So whatever is your language used, make sure to get rid of this specific cookie to get things working back as usual

Comment: This workaround no longer seems to work based on my testing

Comment: looks like not working anymore